# Inherited methods in Spring-Data-Neo4j repository interfaces not working

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have an abstract domain class containing a uid field, looking as below:

```
public abstract class GraphEntityWithUid extends GraphEntity {

    private String uid = CommonUtils.newUid();

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}
```

And, an abstract repository for it:

```
public abstract interface GraphEntityWithUidRepository<T extends GraphEntityWithUid> extends GraphRepository<T> {

    public T findByUid(String uid);
}
```

I have a concrete domain class that inherits the uid, looking as below:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Attachment extends GraphEntityWithUid {

    ...
}
```

And, its repository looks as below:

```
public interface AttachmentRepository extends GraphEntityWithUidRepository<Attachment> {

}
```

Now, when I use the `findByUid` method as below:

```
// returns null
attachmentRepository.findByUid(uid);
```

it always returns null. However, if I re-declare the method in the `AttachmentRepository` as below, it works properly:

```
public interface AttachmentRepository extends GraphEntityWithUidRepository<Attachment> {

    // Shouldn't this be automatically inherited??
    public Attachment findByUid(String uid);
}
```

Why should I need to re-declare `findByUid` method in `AttachmentRepository`? Shouldn't it be automatically inherited from `GraphEntityWithUidRepository`?

Comment: Which version of SDN?

Comment: 4.1.2.RELEASE (Actually I'm using Boot 1.4 and all the versions that come with spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j)